# Analytics on mod tools broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

I'm getting this error on the analytics tab:
Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8) Timestamp: Fri, 9 Dec 2011 20:32:32 UTC
>
> Message: 'window.G_vmlCanvasManager' is null or not an object Line: 1
>   Char: 14660 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/jquery.flot.min.js?v=be91c8ecb518

Comment: I get this in IE8 on XP for both Android and Music. I suggest migrating to MSO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funny thing, it helps if you use the correct path to a script if you want that script to work.  Who knew?!

This is fixed, pending a build.

Comment: heh, yeah, that tends to help.  it's working now, thanks!